# What is a better way to organize my functions for event listeners?

Tags: javascript, function, events

I'm fairly new to programming and I have a few buttons that I want to add event listeners to - and eventually remove the listeners.

I went ahead and did things the non-recommended way repeating myself a bunch and making a function for each button event. I'm looking for a way to write cleaner code.

At first I tried adding anonymous functions for each button, but had to find out the hard way that I can't remove those listeners if I use that method.

Here's where I repeated myself which is not recommended. Each function is meant for just one button. I basically did it for the sake of getting the program to work...

```
const hamburger = function(){
  yourOrder('Hamburger');
};

const fries = function(){
  yourOrder('Fries');
};

const soda = function(){
  yourOrder('Soda');
};

const iceCream = function(){
  yourOrder('Ice Cream');
};

const complete = function(){
  yourOrder('complete');
  El.finish.addEventListener('click', finish);
};

const finish = function(){
  yourOrder('finish');
};

const reset = function(){
  yourOrder('reset');
};
```

Here's the buttons in question which are currently calling those above functions on each click...

```
const setupEventListeners = function(){

  El.hamburger.addEventListener('click', hamburger);
  El.fries.addEventListener('click', fries);
  El.soda.addEventListener('click', soda);
  El.iceCream.addEventListener('click', iceCream);
  El.complete.addEventListener('click', complete);
  El.reset.addEventListener('click', reset);

};
```

Then here's a separate function what happens when you click a button...

```
const yourOrder = function(order){
   if(order === 'Hamburger'){
    Some action...
   } else if(order === 'Fries'){
      Some action...
   } else if(order === 'Soda'){
      Some action...
   } else if(order === 'Ice Cream'){
      Some action...
   } else if(order === 'complete'){
      Some action... 
   } else if(order === 'finish'){
      Some action...
   } else {
      Some action...
  }
};
```

If the 'complete' button is clicked, I want the other buttons to become disabled until the user clicks the 'finish' button. I've accomplished that with this code, but I know there's a better way to achieve this without building a separate function containing a different parameter for the yourOrder function. I'm just not sure what that is. Any advise would be helpful.

Here is my HTML if anyone is interested. I'm sure it's all very atrocious, but be gentle. I'm learning along the way...

```
<div id='topHeadings'>
  <div id='topContainer'>
    <h1 id='title'>Choose from the Menu Below</h1>
    <div id='totalContainer'>
      <h2 id='total'>Total:</h2>
      <h2 id='totalText'>$0.00</h2>
    </div>
    <div id='topButtonContainer'>
      <button class='button' id='complete'>Complete Order</button>
      <button class='button' id='reset'>Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id='topHeadings'>
  <div id='topContainer'>
    <h1 id='title'>Choose from the Menu Below</h1>
    <div id='totalContainer'>
      <h2 id='total'>Total:</h2>
      <h2 id='totalText'>$0.00</h2>
    </div>
    <div id='topButtonContainer'>
      <button class='button' id='complete'>Complete Order</button>
      <button class='button' id='reset'>Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id = 'menuContainer'>
  <div id = 'menu'>
    <button class='button' id='hamburger'>Hamburger</button>
    <button class='button' id='fries'>Fries</button>
    <button class='button' id='soda'>Soda</button>
    <button class='button' id='iceCream'>Ice Cream</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id = 'priceContainer'>
  <div id = 'price'>
    <h3 class = 'p'>$3.99</h3>
    <h3 class = 'p'>$1.99</h3>
    <h3 class = 'p'>$1.99</h3>
    <h3 class = 'p'>$0.99</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<div id='imageContainer'>
  <img id='order' height='350px'>
</div>

<div id='receipt'>
  <p>9/5/19 10:39pm</p>
  <p>Order 101</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Hamburger: $3.99</li>
    <li>Fries: $1.99</li>
    <li>Soda: $1.99</li>
    <li>Ice Cream: $0.99</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Total: $8.96</p>
  <p>Thank you for your order!</p>
  <button class='button' id='finish'>Finish</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Show Your html. It's easier to just set 1 event listener on the parent and see if e.target is a element of interest.

Comment: that won't improve the quality of the code though - he's basically already doing that with the endless `if`'s

Comment: Without knowing what `Some action...` is, that can't be helped.

Comment: Yeah @ACDev what is `Some action...` in between these?  Are they significantly different each time?

Comment: @Deryck For the buttons indicating food, "Some action..." is going to show an image of said order then it's going to add a price to the overall program total. For 'complete', a receipt shows up on the application with a finish button. Once that receipt becomes available, all other buttons should become disabled until that finish button is clicked. The 'reset' button simply clears any current image and clears the program total.

Comment: @TheMaster I'm sure you're probably referring to Event Delegation yeah? I was looking into that, but couldn't quite get the hang of it. I went ahead and added the HTML to the question. Thank you everyone for your help. This is my first full program I've written solo.

Comment: switch statements instead of all those if statements...

Comment: @ACDev, you can illustrate your point of doing things this way with a minimal working code. use the snippet `<>` button on the editor menu. it makes it easier to show you how things could be done better. BTW, I was wondering where the `El` variable first came into the scene :)

Comment: @Udo E. The <> button on my editor wasn't much help. Although I could probably stand to get a newer editor. I currently use Komodo and the snippet button didn't really show me much other than something that isn't being called. The El variable is "const El = UICtrl.getElements();". I have a few IIFEs talking to each other and the El variable is receiving all the document.getElementByIds that are housed in another IIFE. Trying to build good habits with organization. My calculations, UI code snippets and main controller are in different IIFEs.

Comment: @ACDev, i mean the editor here on stack overflow - the one you use to write and edit your question. Sorry, if I wasn't clear. It  has a file icon with `<>` inside it. You can write a complete code snippet that can be run and tested here on stack overflow. All you need to do is capture only the aspect of the code you want to improve. See this link for a little more help : (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a runnable snippet of event delegation:

```html
    <div id ="main">
    <div id='topHeadings'>
      <div id='topContainer'>
        <h1 id='title'>Choose from the Menu Below</h1>
        <div id='totalContainer'>
          <h2 id='total'>Total:</h2>
          <h2 id='totalText'>$0.00</h2>
        </div>
        <div id='topButtonContainer'>
          <button class='button' id='complete'>Complete Order</button>
          <button class='button' id='reset'>Reset</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id = 'menuContainer'>
      <div id = 'menu'>
        <button class='button' id='hamburger'>Hamburger</button>
        <button class='button' id='fries'>Fries</button>
        <button class='button' id='soda'>Soda</button>
        <button class='button' id='iceCream'>Ice Cream</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id = 'priceContainer'>
      <div id = 'price'>
        <h3 class = 'p'>$3.99</h3>
        <h3 class = 'p'>$1.99</h3>
        <h3 class = 'p'>$1.99</h3>
        <h3 class = 'p'>$0.99</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div id='imageContainer'>
      <img id='order' height='350px'>
    </div>

    <div id='receipt'>
      <p>9/5/19 10:39pm</p>
      <p>Order 101</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Hamburger: $3.99</li>
        <li>Fries: $1.99</li>
        <li>Soda: $1.99</li>
        <li>Ice Cream: $0.99</li>
      </ul>
      <p>Total: $8.96</p>
      <p>Thank you for your order!</p>
      <button class='button' id='finish'>Finish</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var main = document.getElementById('main');
      const handleClick = e => {
       let el = e.target;
       if(el.tagName ==='BUTTON'){
        alert("Button "+ el.id + " was clicked");
        el.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
        //yourOrder(el.id);
       }
      };
      main.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
    </script>
```

### References:

- [Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)